# Why do I return an error of renderEvents undefined (fullcalendar)

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am practicing Json and Jquery and I want to understand why I am returning an error of renderEvents undefined, this is my code that when you click a select option with the id "#search" it would populate a data on this class ".order-details-table". I have not applied a filter yet I just want to appear the JSON file using the following command.

```
$("#search").change(function(){

var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET','events.json');
ourRequest.onload = function(){
var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText); 

renderEvents(ourData); 



 };

ourRequest.send();


}),

function renderEvents(calEvent , jsEvent , view){

    function insert(title, product, url, time, location){
        $(".order-details-table").append('<tr><td class="o-box-name"><a name="detailsevent">'+ product +'</a></td><td class="o-box-name">'+title+'<br><small>'+time+'</small><small>&nbsp'+location+'</small></td><td><a href="'+ url +'" class="cancel-del-text" target=_"blank">Register!</a></td></tr>');
      };

      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".calendar").offset().top }, 1500);

      $(".order-details-table").empty(); // Clear list of products

      for (var i = 0; i < calEvent.products.length; i++) {
        insert(calEvent.title, calEvent.products[i].name, calEvent.products[i].url,  calEvent.products[i].time,  calEvent.products[i].location);
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's because the function `renderEvents` expects 3 parameters and when you call it you pass just the response. I guess you could just replace `function renderEvents(calEvent , jsEvent , view)` with `function renderEvents(calEvent)` since those 2 other parameters aren't used.

Comment: still having the same error when I remove the other two parameters

Comment: there's also a typo after `ourRequest.send();`, replace `}),` with `});` and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you it reflects another error  calEvent.products is undefined , does it mean it can't access the JSON file? , @Signo

Comment: You're welcome! Yes that error means that the json structure is not what you're expecting. You can `console.log(calEvent)` to see what you receive from the `GET` request